# Command to keep only a portion of JSON data from each line?

Tags: text-processing, sed, string, json

I have test.json file with different lengths of rows. Some fictitious example:

```
{ "a" : 123, "b": "sd", "c": 45, "d": 1, "e": "" }
{ "a": 5, "b": "bfgg", "c": "x4c", "d": 31, "e": "" }
```

I want to just keep just b for every line:

```
{ "b": "sd"}
{ "b": "bfgg"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a proper [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) tool:

```
jq -c '{"b": .b}' test.json
```

The output:

```
{"b":"sd"}
{"b":"bfgg"}
```

Comment: Or just `jq -c '{b}' test.json`

Answer (score 7):

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --json cut -f b test.json
{ "b": "sd" }
{ "b": "bfgg" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) json parser:

```
json -f test.json -gac 'return console.log("{ \"b\": \"" + this.b + "\" }")'
```

In this case `jq` seems like a better tool for this but I still think `json` is a really great tool for parsing json data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with `cut` and `sed`:

```
cut -d',' -f2 file | sed -e 's/^/{/' -e 's/$/ }/'
```

Output:

```
{ "b": "sd" }
{ "b": "bfgg" }
```

Comment: Is this location dependant? I can't decypher why this works specifically for key `b`.

Comment: This works only because the example input always has "b" in the 2nd field. So it might be useful if you're on some system where you can't/don't want to install one of the fancier tools, but ONLY IF you can be absolutely sure the json formatting will never change.